# How do I insert a new record into the database with CakePHP 3.0?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

My CakePHP 3.0 app uses a MySQL database, which currently has 2 tables with identical structures (but different data). I want to merge these 2 tables, but to keep track of the data, as it has associations.

So, I figured I'd just read in the records from one table, and copy them into the other table with a flag to indicate that they're from the old table, like this:

```
public function copyarchive() {
    $oldalbums= TableRegistry::get('Archivealbums');
    $newalbums= TableRegistry::get('Albums');
    $albumlist = $oldalbums->find(); // Get all archived albums
    foreach($albumlist as $oldalbum) {
        // Copy album details to album table and get new id
        $newalbum = $newalbums->newEntity([
                    'is_archive' => 1,
                    'name' => $oldalbum->name,
                    'date' => $oldalbum->date,
                    'description' => $oldalbum->description,
                    'order' => $oldalbum->order,
        ]);
        if ($newalbums->save($newalbum)) {
            $id = $newalbum->id;
            // ... now do other things ...
        }
     }
 }
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order) VALUES (1, 'Pre-1920\'s', '2013-10-22 23:00:00', '<p>\r\n  Photos from bef' at line 1
```

and the SQL query is listed as:

```
INSERT INTO albums (is_archive, name, date, description, order) VALUES (:c0, :c1, :c2, :c3, :c4)
```

It also suggests "Could this be caused by using Auto-Tables?"

Am I doing something silly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**order** is a MySQL protected word for use in ordering results. I would either use a different column name or using backticks in your code may work:

```
public function copyarchive() {
    $oldalbums= TableRegistry::get('Archivealbums');
    $newalbums= TableRegistry::get('Albums');
    $albumlist = $oldalbums->find(); // Get all archived albums
    foreach($albumlist as $oldalbum) {
        // Copy album details to album table and get new id
        $newalbum = $newalbums->newEntity([
                    'is_archive' => 1,
                    'name' => $oldalbum->name,
                    'date' => $oldalbum->date,
                    'description' => $oldalbum->description,
                    '`order`' => $oldalbum->order,
        ]);
        if ($newalbums->save($newalbum)) {
            $id = $newalbum->id;
            // ... now do other things ...
        }
     }
 }
```

The SQL error indeed tells you of the problem. In general do not use MySQL protected words in your schema.

Comment: That however can prevent marshalling and validation from working properly, as the field in the schema and the validator will not match anymore. One should enable [**auto-quoting**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#identifier-quoting) instead (in case renaming the column isn't possible).

Comment: Good call, the developer can also enable this within app.php using 'quoteIdentifiers' =>true https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#configuration

Comment: auto-quoting is a workaround, better to fix the schema to not use protected words. Also I'm not sure if auto-quoting has a performance impact. I consider it as a workaround for legacy DBs, we've used it until we've got all the crap in our ~300 tables fixed.

Comment: Funny I realized after answering this question that I have this unfortunate workaround in place for my legacy application. Sigh.